# Only want Log to be stored in logger, not displayed in console?

Tags: c#, log4net

Using the example of log4net from:

http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/log4net-tutorial-in-c-net-how-can-i-show-log-in-a-file/

I am using a command input parameter 'User' or 'NoUser'.
User will output the text ONLY to the console, while NoUser will output the text ONLY to the log file. From the example I have got it working, but when 'NoUser' is entered it writes the text to the output file AND console app.

So im using a static class to set User/No user:

```
public static class Log
{
    public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    public static bool _user;

    public static void UseLog4Net(string msg)
    {
        if (_user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        } 
        else
        {
            log.Debug(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Then from the program I try to test:

```
assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool verbose = false;
    bool user = false;

    try
    {
        OutputHeader();

        ProcessParameters(args, out verbose, out user);

        Log._verbose = verbose;
        Log._user = user;
    }
}

private static void ProcessParameters(string[] args, out bool verbose, out bool user)
{
    verbose = CheckArgs(args, "verbose", "quiet");           
    user = CheckArgs(args, "user", "nouser");

    if (!user)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST 1");

        //Console.SetOut(File.CreateText(@".\log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".log"));
        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();

        Log.UseLog4Net("ABC");

        Console.ReadLine();  

        OutputHeader();
    }
}

private static bool CheckArgs(string[] args, string trueValue, string falseValue)
{
    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        if (arg.ToLower() == trueValue.ToLower())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (arg.ToLower() == falseValue.ToLower())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here ABC is written to the console and text file. I only want it to be written to text file.

Any ideas?

**Update**

```
<configSections>
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <param name="File" value="C:\Try\logger\logger\bin\Debug\log + "Monday" + .txt" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Please show what `_user` is. Are you absolutely positively sure that this is the only code being executed? How does your log4net configuration look?

Comment: Regarding your edit: you've still not told us anything. What is `user`?

Comment: user is an input parameter from the command line argument, user will show text in console app, nouser will only show text in text file

Comment: Please just add the code that demonstrates how you get the value of `user`. Does it work when you simply do `user = true;`?

Comment: there is no code to get the value I am right clicking on the project, selecting properties, from 'debug' tab, in 'Start Options' I am entering 'DownloadDept verbose nouser' in command line argument

Comment: Does this code even run? `nouser` is not a valid option for a `bool` variable. It must be either `true` or `false`, where are you doing that conversion?